# Remove duplicates groups

Tags: sql-server

I have a many-to-many relationship table (bridge table) (TicketId, CiiD) and I want to transform it into the following model : (IdBridge, Ciid),
actually my problem is how to remove the duplicates groups ! 
here is an exemple code for source table (TicketCis):

**TicketCis**

```
CREATE TABLE TicketCIs
(
      TicketId varchar(5)
      ,CIId varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO TicketCis (TicketId, CiiD)
VALUES 
('A','AA'),
('A','AB'),
('B','AA'),
('C','AC'),
('C','AD'),
('D','AA'),
('E','AC'),
('E','AD'),
('F','AF');
```

so I proceed to grouping by TicketId with adding ID_GROUP with this query:

```
SELECT
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TicketId) AS ID_GROUP,
     CIId
FROM TicketCIs
```

The output I'm getting:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID_GROUP ║ CIId  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╣
║    1     ║  AA   ║
║    1     ║  AB   ║ 
║    2     ║  AA   ║
║    3     ║  AC   ║
║    3     ║  AD   ║
║    4     ║  AA   ║
║    5     ║  AC   ║
║    5     ║  AD   ║
║    7     ║  AF   ║
╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

The output I'd like to get:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID_GROUP ║ CIId  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╣
║    1     ║  AA   ║
║    1     ║  AB   ║ 
║    2     ║  AA   ║
║    3     ║  AC   ║
║    3     ║  AD   ║
║    6     ║  AF   ║
╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

In the output (what I'm looking for) as you can see, the duplicate group_ids (4,5) are removed.

I hope it's clearer now :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT() OVER` window function and `PARTITION` by your ID_GROUP field (in a series of `CTEs`) to filter on in the final query.

```
WITH CTE_Group AS
(
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TicketId) AS ID_GROUP,
        CIId
    FROM TicketCIs
),
CTE_Group_Distinct AS
(
    SELECT
        ID_Group,
        CIId,
        COUNT(CIId) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_GROUP) AS DupeCount
    FROM CTE_Group 
)

SELECT ID_GROUP, CIId
FROM CTE_Group_Distinct
WHERE DupeCount = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I found the solution for my problem here is the code :

```
WITH CTE_Group AS
(
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TicketId) AS ID_GROUP,
    TicketId,
    CIId
FROM TicketCIs
),
CTE_Group_Checksum AS 
(SELECT 
    ID_Group,
    CIId,
    CHECKSUM_AGG(Convert(int, Convert(varbinary(5), CIId))) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_GROUP) AS Check_grp
FROM CTE_Group
)

SELECT  
ID_Group,
CIId
FROM CTE_Group_Checksum
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT 
    Check_grp,
    MIN(ID_Group) filtred_group
FROM CTE_Group_Checksum
GROUP BY Check_grp) Filtred
on ID_GROUP = filtred_group
ORDER BY    
ID_Group,
CIId
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `CIId`s are indeed that short (`varchar(5)`) and there cannot be very many of them per `TicketId`, you could also try using `STRING_AGG` in a similar fashion to `CHECKSUM_AGG`:

```
WITH
  GroupsAggregated AS
  (
    SELECT
      TicketId
    , CIIdAgg = STRING_AGG(CAST(CiiD AS char(5)), '')
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CIId ASC)
    FROM
      TicketCIs
    GROUP BY
      TicketId
  )
, GroupsRanked AS
  (
    SELECT
      MinTicketId = MIN(TicketId)
    FROM
      GroupsAggregated
    GROUP BY
      CIIdAgg
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TicketCIs
WHERE
  TicketId IN (SELECT MinTicketId FROM GroupsRanked)
;
```

You can use [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75b9fa2d65d16f3f52fd817610d9c048) to play with a live demo of the method.

Comment: Thanks @Andriy M, in reality it's uniqueidentifier with varchar(36), so I think checksum it's better

Comment: @KiMaN: Fair enough. Are TicketIds `uniqueidentifier` as well? Is that why you are generating rankings on them to be used with `MIN` instead of applying the `MIN` directly to `TicketId`?

Comment: Yes the TicketId as well, but STRING_AGG doesn't work for me (SQL SERVER 2016) so I can't test